# Attach extra information at every level of a recursive data type?

Tags: haskell, category-theory, recursive-datastructures, fixpoint-combinators

(This is not specifically a Haskell question.)

I have a recursive data structure. I would like to attach some kind of extra information at every level of it. Here's a simplified example, in which I'm adding either an `X` or a `Y` to every level of a tree:

```
import Data.Functor.Foldable

data Wrap a = X a | Y a
  deriving Show

data TreeF a b = Leaf a | TreeF a b b
  deriving Show

depth1 :: Wrap (TreeF Int ())
depth1 = X (Leaf 1)

depth2 :: Wrap (TreeF Int (Wrap (TreeF Int ())))
depth2 = Y (TreeF 1 (X $ Leaf 1) (Y $ Leaf 1))

-- depthInfinity :: Fix something something ...
```

(The definition of `TreeF` is, to me, unnatural. I would prefer to define `data Tree a = Leaf a | Tree a (Tree a) (Tree a)`, but I can't figure out how to state my question if I do that. So instead I've written it in the form of a `Base` functor, ala [Data.Functor.Foldable](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/recursion-schemes-5.1.2/docs/Data-Functor-Foldable.html).)

The `Wrap` type can be used to attach the information `X` or `Y` to some kind of data. `depth1'` is a depth-1 `TreeF` in which the `Wrap` flag has been attached at every level (it's only got one level). `depth2` is a depth-2 `TreeF` in which, again, the `Wrap` flag has been attached at every level (it's got two levels).

How can I create a "Wrapped Tree" of arbitrary depth? How should I write its type signature? Is there a category-theoretic term for this kind of data mashup?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use

```
Fix (Compose Wrap (TreeF Int))
```

but I probably wouldn't. If you definitely want to go the open recursion route, making your own variant of `Fix` is probably sanest:

```
data WrapData = X | Y
data LabeledFix a f = Labeled a (f (LabeledFix a f))
-- ... and then use LabeledFix WrapData (TreeF Int)
```

But even saner still is to just use plain old closed recursion. You don't even have to make your type any more special than it already was; just:

```
data Tree a = Leaf a | Branch a (Tree a) (Tree a)
-- ... and then use Tree (WrapData, Int)
```

Comment: My example was bad -- in fact the recursive `Expr` data type I'm working with is not a `Functor` (although now I wonder whether it should be). Therefore your excellent last solution does not apply. Instead I went with something like your second suggestion: I define `newtype ExprFWith b a = EFW (b, ExprF a)` where `ExprF` is the `Base` `Functor` of `Expr`, and then use `Fix (ExprFWith x)` to attach an `x` at every level of an `Expr`.

Comment: @JeffreyBenjaminBrown If you choose that route -- that is, making a modifier for your base functor rather than a modified `Fix` -- then I do recommend `type ExprFWith b = Compose ((,) b)` instead. No need to reinvent the wheel!